# alternative for macOS popUpButton in iOS?

Tags: ios

What is the alternative UI element for Pop Up Button (existed for macOS) in iOS? I use Xcode 12.4.
[I am looking for something similar to the picture but in iOS.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTZLZ.png)

Comment: Probably [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview). You can make it look like a context menu with [MenuPickerStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menupickerstyle)

Comment: Do you want it in UIKit or in SwiftUI?